# Don't know why I am getting a linking error

Tags: c, linker, x86, linker-errors

I don't know why I am getting this linking error, I am pretty sure everything is linked correctly

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o test driver.c target.c 
driver.c:8: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’
ld: duplicate symbol _first in /var/folders/yx/31ddgzsj4k97jzvwhfx7tkz00000gn/T//ccw2n48G.o and /var/folders/yx/31ddgzsj4k97jzvwhfx7tkz00000gn/T//ccKZdUlG.o for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have the following code, which is a simple linked list, but I don't know why it wont compile

driver.c

```
 #include "target.h"
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

char * prog;
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
  prog = argv[0];
  print_target_list(1);
  .....
```

target.c

```
#include "target.h"
/* This function returns true if there is a target with name in the target linked list */
bool is_target(char * name){
    struct target_node * ptr = first;
   while(ptr != NULL){
    if(strcmp(ptr->name,name) == 0){
      return true;
    }
    ptr = ptr->next;
  }
  return false;
}
......
```

target.h

```
#ifndef TARGET_H
#define TARGET_H

//#include "source.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*-----------------------------------------*/

extern char * prog;

/*-----------------------------------------*/

struct source_node{
  char * name;
};

struct target_node{
  char * name;
  struct target_node * next;
  struct source_node * src_node;
};

struct target_node * first = NULL;

/*-----------------------------------------------------*/


/* return 1 if name is in the target linked list 0 otherwise */
bool is_target(char * name);
/* returns a new target_node */ 
struct target_node * new_target_node(char * name);
/* insert a new target_node into the list */
void insert_target_node(char * name);
/* remove a target_node from the list */
void remove_target_node(char * name);
/* print the current linked list */
void print_target_list(int opts);


#endif
```

Any help would be appricated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `target.h` use:

```
extern struct target_node * first;
```

And place the following in the appropriate target.c file:

```
struct target_node * first = NULL;
```

If `first` isn't needed outside of `target.c`, it can be removed from `target.h` altogether (and maybe made `static` in `target.c` if you want to avoid putting it in the global namespace needlessly).

Answer (score 1):

Objects with external linkage have to be defined only once in the entire program.

You defined `struct target_node * first` in a header file and then included that header file it into two different implementation files. Now you have two definitions of `first` in your program. And `first` is an object with external linkage. Hence the error.

Comment: would it be better to make it extern in the header file or extern in the target.c file? What would make more sense/common place

Comment: @Greg: make it `extern` in the header - all users of the object need to get the `extern` declaration so they don't define it. Only the 'owner' of the object gets to define/initialize it.